# Is DataRowCollection thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, ado.net, thread-safety

I want to add row to Table.Rows collection in multi thread environment. e.g:

```
DataTable dt = CreateDataTable(...);
Parallel.For(0, 100, (i, loopState)=>{
    DataRow row = GetRow(...);
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
});
```

So, is Tables.Rows thread safe ?

Comment: Your question is answered in the official documentation. Didn't you try a simple Google search? You're basically asking people to do basic research for you.

Comment: It's place at the bottom of page and I have leave out it. thanks @Filkolev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations.You must
>   synchronize any write operations.